# Alias Template with non-type template parameter

Tags: c++

My expectation was that this code cannot be compiled, but it can. How can this code work ?
Even integer is not a template.

```cpp
template <int>
using A = int;

void f(A<4> foo = 0);
```

Doesn't it come this way?

```cpp
void f(int<4> foo = 0);
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude all of the `A`s are the same type, because it's an alias template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Doesn't it come this way?

No.

`A` is an alias template. It has an unnamed unused `int` parameter. No matter what argument is used `A` is always an alias for `int`. Thats what `using A = int;` means.

The function declaration is basically just

```
void f(int foo = 0);
```

---

Perhaps you are not familiar with unnamed unused template parameter. The alias can be equivalently written as:

```
template <int Value>
using A = int;
```

As `Value` is not used its name can be ommitted.

---

Perhaps you are confused by `int` appearing twice in the alias template. The first `int` is the (unnamed unused) parameter, the second `int` is the aliased type, the two are unrelated.

You can write similar alias with a `int` parameter to alias `double`:

```
template <int>
using B = double;
```

Here any `B<n>` is an alias for `double`.

Or you can write similar alias with a type parameter to alias `int`:

```
template <typename>
using C = int;
```

Here any `C<T>`, eg `C<std::string>` or `C<foo>` is an alias for `int`.